# Regarding the new EF5 auto-compiled queries feature

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I've made few tests regarding the new EF5 auto-compiled queries feature. The problem is that I don't see any difference in the performance.

I've made one project with .NET 4.0 and EF4.0 without using compiled queries. 
I've made another project with .NET 4.0 and EF4.0 with compiled queries - there was 50% improvement in performance.

And then I tried to create a project with EF 5.0, in which there was basically no difference in performance.

All the projects were asp.net mvc (first two were version 3, the last one - version 4).

Am I missing something here ? Is there something special I need to do to enable the auto-compile feature ? I just created MVC 4 project with pre-build EF5 inside.

The query I am testing with is rather verbose, three joins and multiple filters inside.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Auto compiled queries are available in the part of EF5 live in the .NET Framework 4.5. If you are running EF5 on .NET Framework 4 queries are not automatically compiled.

Comment: The good news is auto-compiled queries feature is now avaiable with EF6 Alpha and .NET Framework 4.

Comment: Pawel,

Thanks for answering. Actually, I downloaded .NET 4.5 from the MS site :

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30653

I installed it, I also got .NET 4.5 target as a setting in the project tab in Visual Studio and it's set. But when I look at the assemblies, they are all 4.0 .

I am not sure why this is happening.

Comment: I also downloaded EF6 alpha. I still don't see any performance optimizations.

Comment: .NET Framework 4.5 is an in-place update. This means that assemblies version will be 4.0. Only the build number changes.

Comment: I see. But still no performance improvements. Any ideas why ?

Comment: What are you comparing - is it a .NET Framework 4 app with manually compiled queries against EF5 with auto-compiled queries? If this is the case then performance characteristics will be similar. The difference is between EF4 doing anything special (i.e. no query compilation) against EF5 (queries are automatically compiled). There are some additional perf improvements in EF5 you may or may not see depending on the query. Note that once you install .NET 4.5 you cannot compare against .NET 4 on the same machine - since this it an in-place update .NET Framework 4.5 is always used at runtime.

Comment: Hi Pawel,

I am comparing EF 4.0 agains EF 5.0 and I don't see any benefit in performance. I also checked the result manually using the CompiledQuery class and I saw a significant improvement.

Comment: Is it on one machine or on two different machines. If this is just on one machine and you have .NET Framework 4.5 on it than you are not comparing EF5 vs EF5 anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Pawel,

Thanks for answering. Actually, I downloaded .NET 4.5 from the MS site :

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30653

I installed it, I also got .NET 4.5 target as a setting in the project tab in Visual Studio and it's set. But when I look at the assemblies, they are all 4.0 .

I am not sure why this is happening.

I also upgraded to EF 6.0 alpha.

Still absolutely no performance improvement.

Comment: Please use the 'add comment' feature to place comments instead of placing an answer (since this is not an answer to your question).

Comment: .NET Framework 4.5 is an in-place update. It replaces .NET Framework 4. Note that even if you target your application at .NET Framework 4 at it will use .NET Framework 4.5 at runtime. This means that you cannot compare performance of a .NET Framework 4 app against an .NET Framework 4.5 app on the same machine since both will use .NET Framework 4.5.

Comment: I see, thanks for the info. But I still change EF 4 to EF 5, shouldn't the performance be different ? Because in my case it's the same.