# Does Entity Framework 6 precompile queries with .Net Framework 4.0

Tags: entity-framework, .net-4.0, entity-framework-6, precompiled

Question title really says it all, but I can't seem to find this tidbit of information anywhere.  A comment here ( https://stackoverflow.com/a/13224381/215068) is the best I've found.

Will EF 6 (6.0.1) precompile views when using the .NET Framework 4.0?

**EDIT** -- sorry, totally meant query plan caching (I had EdmGen and precompiled-views on the brain)

Comment: Are you interested in pre-compiled views or pre-compiled queries?

Comment: Yes, I meant query plan compilation and caching.  Just a short circuit between the ears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it does because EF6 should bring all features from EF5 + .NET 4.5 back to .NET 4.0.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the *views* are automatically pre-compiled upon start.